# Can expo-based npm packages be used in react-native project or vice-versa?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I want to build a **npm package** for **react-native**. Before I get started I have some question in my mind:

- Should I start with **expo** or bare **react-native**?
- If I start with expo, will it run successfully on react-native project or vice-versa?
- If no, then what's the solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes for both cases, but needs some time to configure

Almost all of expo packages can be used inside a CLI app, you can follow this link for more details:
https://docs.expo.dev/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/

As for using packages that aren't meant for expo then you also can achieve that but you have to differentiate between two different cases:

1- Packages that include Native Modules: the process is a little more complicated but can be achieved without ejecting, checkout EAS https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/

2- JS/TS only packages: usually you can install those safely if they are compatible with your configs

My suggestion is that you should try to build an app with both bare and expo to get a feel of what expo's benefits and drawbacks are, although in the current state of expo you should be able to achieve anything without having to eject.